# Would this derivation of an integral formula be valid?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, functions

So, employing the method of synthetic division, I derived that

[image]

or in much simpler form

[image]

Given this, my question is, would the following statement be valid?

[image]

Comment: You've made a mistake in your derivation--there's no $N-1$ choose $k$ in the difference of powers formula.

Comment: The formula $x^N-a^N = (x-a)(x+a)^{N-1}$ holds for $N = 1$ and $N = 2$, but not higher powers. Try plugging in numbers to see that this is false.

Comment: Oh my mistake. I don't know why I left that coefficient term in the series. Thanks